# How to place currency symbol as suffix for amount in objective-c?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
- (void) currencyFormat {
    double someDouble = 100.00;
    NSNumber *currencyValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:someDouble];
    NSNumberFormatter *formater = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSString *currencyString = [formater stringFromNumber:currencyValue];
    NSLog(@"Value = %@",currencyString);
}
```

I tried above code but it places all currency symbol as prefix. 
What if I want it to place it as suffix? Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is the default behaviour of `NSNumberFormatter` as the doc says:

> Specifies a currency style format; for example, in the en_US_POSIX
>   locale, 1234.5678 is represented as “$ 1234.57”.

If you want the currency at the end, you can do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formater = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setPositiveSuffix:formater.currencySymbol];
[formater setNegativeSuffix:formater.currencySymbol];
NSString *currencyString = [formater stringFromNumber:currencyValue];
NSLog(@"Value = %@",currencyString);
```